# Is there a way to pass credentials to SCOM rest api through postman ? I am getting 401 error

Tags: scom

I am having trouble with figuring out what should come under json body in the body when sending post rest api call to the scom server I have tried the below one.

```
{
    "credentials":"<base64 coded text of credential>"
    
}
```

And here is the header and body
[image]

[image]

And the error
[image]

And this is the powershell script rest api request which  I tried changing to postmain request

```
 $server="servername"
 
# authentication part
 
$scomHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$scomHeaders.Add('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8')
 
$bodyraw = "Windows"
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($bodyraw)
$EncodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$jsonbody = $EncodedText | ConvertTo-Json
 
$uri = "http:// $server/OperationsManager/authenticate"

$username = "username.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "paswword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)

$Request = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method POST `
    -Uri $uri `
    -Headers $scomHeaders `
    -body $jsonbody `
    -Credential $cred `
    -SessionVariable 'websession'
```

I also tried using the help of [I want to fetch the SCOM alerts data. But I keep getting the error 401. I am passing the credentials right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167121/i-want-to-fetch-the-scom-alerts-data-but-i-keep-getting-the-error-401-i-am-pas)  post. And still could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

SCOM Supports Basic Authentication as part of the Header. Here is an article on it:
https://mevansit.blogspot.com/2017/03/scom-web-availability-monitoring-with.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)